# apt-get: hash sum mismatch

Tags: linux-mint, apt

Running "sudo apt-get update" results in:

> W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy-security_main_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
>
> W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
>
> W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy_universe_binary-amd64_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
>
> W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy_main_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
>
> W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I have tried to run:

> sudo rm -R /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
>
> sudo rm -fR /var/lib/apt/lists/*
>
> sudo apt-get clean

I have also tried the Fix MergeList problems button of the Software Sources tool. I am running Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon 64 bits.

In the Update Manager I can see many updates that I should install but attempting to install them results in:

> E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en (1)
> E: Problem opening /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages
> E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
> E: _cache->open() failed, please report.

Any ideas?

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Was caused by running linux inside a vm on my laptop which contained an internet filter. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116641/how-do-you-fix-apt-get-update-hash-sum-mismatch

Answer (score 3):

Those messages are normally due to failures during the download of the list or a glitch in the mirror. You can fix it by removing the faulty lists:

> $ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy_universe_binary-amd64_Package

and updating with `sudo apt-get update`. If it still happens use another mirror or wait for a bit first.

Comment: Running the command actually helped for a little while, but after a few days, the problem is back. Changing mirror did not help.

Comment: @user254173 is a problem with the servers or your internet connection, not something you can "fix" localy.

Answer (score 1):

I may assume after you've been removing the files in /var/lib/apt/... you did a new `apt-get update`?

You could also try

```
apt-get check -m -f
```

and verify the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to be valid by visiting each repository's address in your browser, it should give a file listing.