# Error for the following command sudo apt-get update (Some errors have been excluded)

Tags: ubuntu, repository, software-updates

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Translation-en_IN           
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rebecca/upstream Translation-en              
Fetched 284 kB in 11s (23.9 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://extra.linuxmint.com rebecca Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 3EE67F3D0FF405B2 Clement Lefebvre (Linux Mint Package Repository v1) <root@linuxmint.com>

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)



W: Failed to fetch http://packages.linuxmint.com/dists/rebecca/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/munin-plugins/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/munin-plugins/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/munin-plugins/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Re: the error with official repositories (linuxmint/Ubuntu) read this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118912/252181 . Then you also need to remove the manually added PPA (munin-plugins) because it doesn't exist / doesn't support your release. Please avoid following old guides if you don't know what you're doing, i.e., without assuring the instructions are still valid for your specific release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

> sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

Then

> sudo apt-get update

Comment: The following errors occur  
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1397BC53640DB551
> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/munin-plugins